# Garage conduit a few questions

Tags: conduit

Trying to live in a new house.
The garage only has one outlet. I would like to put several more around the walls to facilitate my woodworking hobby.

1. more light.
   There are two fixtures with a single bulb each. Is it acceptable to use those to wire several tube LED light fitures? I want it bright in there.
2. surface mount conduit.
   The panel is flush mounted an all the wires are behind the wall. How do you transition from behind the drywall to surface mounted conduit?
3. air condition for garage.
   I desire to put a mini-split air in the garage because it is very hot here in the summer. Can I run 30amp through the attic and out the soffit?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, my solution for lighting was to rework the central lighting junction box to make it a switched outlet box, and plug four corded LED shop lamps into that. Double the light of my old fluorescent-tube fixtures at a fraction of the power demand.

Tools are on their own circuits.

Answer (score -1):

I have added a lighting junction box [image]

on top of the existing light junction. See pics. This is enough power for LED lights as I’ve been using this for 12 years in my garage.

For wood working hobbies, I also added a retractable extension cord, [image]

so I can cut, sand and plug in my shop vac all in the garage or side of the house. Note, it will be a switched outlet… so I need to turn the garage light on to use the extension cord. Not a big deal, but not perfect.

Ideally you are plugging all power tools into a receptacle/outlet that is 20 Amps. Most lights are run off of 15 Amp circuits. I’ve found if using 15 Amp you might get a bit of dimming of lights when you fire up your  circular saw or chop saw. [image]

Comment: Is this actually legal where you are?  It sure is not where I live.

Comment: ??? Kid toys near this? I wonder what one would regret the most: impalement, or subsequent electrocution

Comment: Not sure why the DVs, this actually looks like a reasonably good installation (though, TBH, it's hard to tell which way is up in the pics...) Not sure I'd want too many power tools running on one circuit, especially if it's only 15a - too much load (saw & dust collection anyone?) and out go the lights, too. Doesn't _really_ answer the question, though. ([How to write a good answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) is a good reference.)